# Open Layers 3 create a progress bar loader with loadingstrategy.bbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, openlayers-3

I have set my vectorSource like this:

```
var vectorSource = function (date) {
return new ol.source.Vector({
    // Start loader
    loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
        var url = 'urlpath?date=' + date;
        // Show progress bar
        $('#progress').fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                var features = format.readFeatures(data, function () {
                    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
                });
                var source = vectorSource();
                // Add the features not printing on the map but the data is there                    
                source.addFeatures(features);
                // When source is ready, then finish
                if (source.getState() == 'ready') {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        // Hide progress bar
                        $('#progress').fadeOut(750);
                    }, 1000)
                }
            }
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all,
});
```

}

I can read the features but I can't print them into the map. I tried to see if it's a projection issue or try to render the map again but don't know the answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ajax request you can not predict the time needs to load and so make a progress bar. Instead you have allready the `start loading` and `end loading` events.

```
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
        var url = requestedUrl;
        alert("START loading here");
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {                
                var features = geoJSONFormat.readFeatures(data);
                vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
                alert("FINISH loading here");
            }
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});
```

Comment: thanks @pavlos. Is this the best approach to have a loader while the user waits for all the features to load? Ideally, the map baseLayer would load straight away and then the loader hides once all the features are loaded

Comment: Hi @pavlos. I have edited my original question as I'm struggling to print the features into the map.